# Netsuite Saved search to get the items of a transaction

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I am trying to do a saved search in Netsuite to get the items of a transaction.

I want to be able to get the full list of items that appear for one or more transactions say an Item Receipt or Sales Order.

This is what I've done:
Criteria:
Type: Item Receipt:
Date created: today
Main line: true

Results:

Here I've tried Line ID, Line count, Item.

But I don't get any line (item) in the results when I run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `mainline` to true means you only want to include header fields.  If you want to get the items from transaction lines, you must set `mainline` to false.